# How to read data from database with JPA/JPQL Query and Foreign Keys

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am new to JPA and i have a problem with it. Suppose that we have two tables which are related by a ManytoOne association.
table 1: person (idp,name,#idep)
table 2: departement (idep,deptname)

I want to write a jpa query like this query in sql :

```
select person.name,departement.deptname from person,departement where person.idep=department.idep
```

Person.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idp;
private String name;

//Jointures JPA
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_dep")
private Departement dept;

//Getters/Setters
```

Departement.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id_dep;
private String deptname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="departement", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Person> listperson=new ArrayList<Person>();

//getters/setters
```

I tried this attempt but it didn't work:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select p.name,d.deptname " + " from Person a,Department d " + "where a.id_dep =d.id_dep ").getResultList();
```

Comment: Hello. Regarding the SQL query that you tried, there is an alias mistake, you  made **Person a**, but you called the name with **p** in `select p.name`. Is just a misspelled alias there or your query just don't return nothing, or maybe with an error?

Comment: thanks for the reply, It didn't work

Comment: "it didnt work" LOL. Care to tell people WHAT "didn't work" ? What happened? got an exception? in which case post it with its stack trace. No exception? then look at the SQL that was invoked. This is referred to as DEBUGGING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you should query against fields, so `a.id_dep` is not correct. You also called `p.name`, whereas alias for Person is set to `a`. The query should look like:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select a.name, d.deptname " + " from Person a, Department d "
 + "where a.dept.id_dep = d.id_dep ").getResultList();
```

If it doesn't work `join` might be needed.

```
entityManager.createQuery("select p.name, d.deptname " + " from Department d JOIN Department.listperson p "
 + "where d.id_dep = p.dept.id_dep ").getResultList();
```

Although it is probably not ideal solution using JPA, as you can just get values from `listperson` much easier.

Comment: how can I get values from 'listperson'  ?

Comment: You need to call getter `getListperson'. Because of mapped One to Many relationship, getter will return list of Person objects associated with that Department. Do you have getters/setters implemented or it's just a comment?

Comment: I have getters/setters, but do you mean I use the getListperson in place of the query ?

Comment: Thanks, I used getListperson

Comment: I meant using i.e. jpql query for getting Departments and than you can iterate over list of Departements to get list of Person entities associated with each one by calling `getListPerson`.

Answer (score 1):

The query is very simple because the two entities are associated to one another:

```
String queryString = "select p.name,d.deptname from Person p JOIN p.dep d";
List list = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();

// use the result list as follows, for example:
for (Object[] o : list) {
    System.out.println("Person name: " + o[0]);
    System.out.println("Department name: " + o[1]);
}
```

Tip:
Java has naming conventions. One of them is the name of instance fields. So the recommendation is instead of

```
private Integer id_dep
```

write

```
private Integer id; // for examle
```

Actually, the `id` field of an entity is just `id` by convention. If you are interested you can read [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 0):

As are you using JPA , this kind query should be automatically by simply invoking the method **getListPerson()** which returns a List of Person.  The provider, may be are you using (**Hibernate**) should using the JPA annotations in order to create the SQL and execute it for you, when you call the get methods.

**entityManager.createQuery("")** is normally used when you need an specific query that hibernate are not able to do, for e.g when you need return only specific field from an entity e.g Person.